# silverlight navigation project - problem with accessing an xml file in clientbin with a webservice

Tags: xml, silverlight, web-services, silverlight-4.0, clientbin

I'm trying to access my .xml file in the ClientBin with no success.

code:

```
 WebClient xmlClient = new WebClient();
 xmlClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(xmlClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
 Uri uri = new Uri("Antwerpen1.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
 xmlClient.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

While debugging the uri throws the following error: System.InvalidOperationException

The result throws the following error: This operation is not supported for a relative URI

I can access my file with the following path : http://localhost:2546/contentManagement.Web/ClientBin/Antwerpen1.xml

What am I doing wrong?

---

update:
I tried the same code in the code behind of my main page and it worked.
Still no result with the webservice.

---

update2:
I found out it's **not** a problem of the URI but the xmlClient.DownloadStringAsync. The BaseAdress(path where the xml file in my clientbin is stored) is empty for some reason..

, ty in advance

Comment: Your code works perfect to me. Created a blank solution and it worked first time. Is your xap in the same folder as your xml?

Comment: yes, there at the same location.

Comment: In what place didn't work your code?

Comment: The solution has 2 projects a server and a client. At the client the above code is working. But when I try to use the same code on the server I get errors.

Comment: Would it be possible to have your code for an in deep checking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the client access policy for your web service to allow the service to work across domain boundaries.

[The MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has more details, but basically you need a file called `clientaccesspolicy.xml` in the root directory of your web service which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
        <domain uri="*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

This will allow anyone access. To lock it down replace the `*` in the uri with your url.

Comment: I created a clientaccesspolicy.xml at the following path http://localhost:2546/contentManagement.Web/clientaccesspolicy.xml. But still the same result.

Comment: @izar - Is that the location of the web service?

Comment: Thats the place of my Service.cvs